# Infinitely many different solutions of differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Give infinitely many different solutions of the differential equation:

$y'=3y^2-12xy+12x^2+2$

I'm not really sure where to start with this, I don't really know how I'd got about even finding just the general solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Finding "the general solution" is at least as hard as finding "infinitely many solutions", so it's hard to understand what you mean by "just" the general solution.

Comment: If you find a general solution with a parameter that can have infinitely many different values, then you've found infinitely many solutions. To start, notice that $3y^2-12xy+12x^2=3(y-2x)^2$, so the substitution $u=y-2x$ might simplify things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write this as a polynomial of linear $x$ and $y$ as follows:

$y' = 3(y-2x)^2 + 2$

So we now substitute $u = y-2x$ with $u' = -2 + 3u^2 + 2 = 3u^2$.

This is a rather simple differential equation, just taking the antiderivative gives $u(x) = -\frac{1}{3x + C}$. Resubstituting that into the original equation and we have

$y(x) = u(x) + 2x = -\frac{1}{3x+C} + 2x $ which indeed solves the differential equation.

Choosing $C\in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary yields infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is Riccati equation with particular solution
$$y=2x$$
and general solution
$$y=2x-\frac{1}{3x+C}$$